# Is there something that will repeat touchesBegan?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button that when getting pressed will move a node. How can I repeat this non stop while button is pressed. I guess I'm looking for something between touchesBegan and touchesEnded. Something like touchesContinue because I'd like the node to continue moving while the button is pressed. This is what I have so far.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // 1
    leftMove.name = "Left"
    rightMove.name = "Right"

    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if (node.name == "Left") {
            // Implement your logic for left button touch here:
            player.position == CGPoint(x:player.position.x-1, y:player.position.y)
        } else if (node.name == "Right") {
            // Implement your logic for right button touch here:
            player.position = CGPoint(x:player.position.x+1, y:player.position.y)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look up `NSTimer`. Turn it on in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, and turn it off in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSTimer` to repeat the move action. Have the `timer` started on the `Touch Down` and have the timer stopped on either `Touch Up Inside` or `Touch Up Outside`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var button: UIButton!

    var timer: NSTimer!

    leftMove.name = "Left"
    rightMove.name = "Right"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)) as UIButton

        //add Target for .TouchDown events, when user touch down
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.touchDown(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        //add Target for .TouchUpInside events, when user release the touch
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.release(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    func touchDown(sender: UIButton) {
        //start the timer
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.movePlayer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func release(sender: UIButton) {
        //stop the timer
        self.timer.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil

    }

    func movePlayer(sender: NSTimer) {
        //move your stuff here
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if (node.name == "Left") {
            // Implement your logic for left button touch here:
            player.position == CGPoint(x:player.position.x-1, y:player.position.y)
        } else if (node.name == "Right") {
            // Implement your logic for right button touch here:
            player.position = CGPoint(x:player.position.x+1, y:player.position.y)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS IN OBJECTIVE C

i suggest you to use this i  did it with touch down event

create Timer object global

**TOUCH UP INSIDE and Drag and EXIT**

```
- (IBAction)arrowUpUpperLipTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

NSLog(@"SIngle TAPPED");

if (self.timer1) {
    [self.timer1 invalidate];
    self.timer1 = nil;
}

[self arrowUpperLipPosChanged:sender];

}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

**TOUCH DOWN**

```
- (IBAction)arrowUpperLipLongTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"LONG TAPPED");
if (self.timer) {
    [self.timer1 invalidate];
    self.timer1 = nil;
}
_timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(arrowUpperLipTimerAction:) userInfo:sender repeats:YES];
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
- (void) arrowUpperLipPosChanged :(UIButton *) sender {

CGRect frame = self.viewUpperLip.frame;
if (sender.tag == 9001) {
    // UP Arrow Tapped
    frame.origin.y --;
} else if (sender.tag == 9002) {
    frame.origin.y ++;
}
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + frame.size.height / 2, frame.size.width, frame.size.height), self.imgViewGridHEyesCenter.center) && !(CGRectIntersection(frame, [self.view viewWithTag:203].frame).size.height >= frame.size.height)) {
    [self.viewUpperLip setFrame:frame];
}

}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
- (void) arrowUpperLipTimerAction :(NSTimer *) timer {
UIButton *sender = (UIButton *)[timer userInfo];
[self arrowUpperLipPosChanged:sender];
}
```